# Qt Creator _IMP error while connecting to MySql

Tags: c++, mysql, xampp, qt-creator

I'm trying to create an app that connects to my **local MySql** through **XAMPP** and outputs the data into a tableWidget.

After writing all the code for it and correcting all the mistakes, I'm getting 17 errors about "undefined reference to **`_imp__ZN.....'** "

*1st Question*: Do I have to put all my project files inside XAMPP/htdocs like I did using PHP?

*2nd Question*: I've only written something inside main.cpp, did I miss something for other classes or maybe I need something else inside the header file?

I've heard that "*imp_*" problems are related to the compiler, but I'm not sure what to do!

Without further ado, this is my **main.cpp**:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtSql/QSql>
#include <QtGui/QtGui>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QtSql/QSqlDatabase>
#include <QTableWidget>
#include <QtSql/QSqlError>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
QTableWidget* tableWidget = new QTableWidget();
tableWidget->setWindowTitle("Connect to Mysql Database");
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
db.setHostName("localhost");
db.setDatabaseName("pizzeria mabo");
db.setUserName("root");
db.setPassword("");

if (!db.open())
{
    QSqlError err = db.lastError();
    QMessageBox::critical(0, QObject::tr("Database Error"), err.text());
}


MainWindow w;
w.show();

return a.exec();
}
```

And here are my **errors**:

http://i57.tinypic.com/nodow7.png

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the errors mean that you are missing a library containing the necessary symbols. If you are using qmake to build the project you have to enable SQL via "QT += sql". Otherwise you will have to find and add the library manually.